# Recording impressions for DFP served videos without IMA SDK

Tags: google-dfp, vast

I am serving video ads and using custom VAST 3 parser on the client side.

I am firing get requests on the url provided in the Impressions tag under the VAST response.

The impressions are not getting recorded on the dfp server, I have waited enough (for a day). Start events are fired perfectly fine, I can see start events in the reports.

I have used the packet sniffer, and url gets hit, I am sure about it. Am I doing something wrong ?  How do I get this working?

Comment: `start` gets fired when the ad was loaded and playback began, `impression` gets fired when the first frame of the ad gets displayed. Resp.: player starts ad -> event: `start` and if the first frame display was detected -> event: `impression`. Are you sure the player does display your ad?

Comment: my player displays ad. Just resolved this a few minutes ago. I had to url encode the iu parameter in the custom vast tag request to get the appropriate impression url. The strange thing is, I still don't get how DFP processed the request without proper encoded parameters and returned the correct ads in the VAST response, but incorrect impression url. It should have returned nothing.